# How to enable mod_rewrite in php.ini on shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, shared-hosting, suphp

I recently hosted my website in shared hosting the sites mod_rewrite is not working. I there anything I have to add in php.ini file to enable the mod_rewrite option in php.ini file.

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot be enabled via php.ini. If mod_rewrite module is enabled/loaded on a server, then "activate" it in .htaccess via `RewriteEngine On`. Alternatively you will have to implement URL routing using PHP itself (check how popular frameworks do this) .. or look for another hosting.

Answer (score 2):

You can in your

```
<VirtualHost *:80> RewriteEngine On</VirtualHost>
```

in your httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks @Digital,
 Is there any other option to enable mod rewrite. because in my hosting plan I don't have option to access httpd.conf.

Comment: I imagine putting the same line of code in a `.htaccess` file would do the same thing.