# 404 file not found error in live server website is based on codeignitter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, live

Recently, I have hosted a website using godaddy. When I enter the domain name in url first page is loading without error, Now when I click on any link or button  on the first page[home page], it is giving 404: file not found error.

**EDIT: .htaccess file from root folder:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule> 
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M 
php_value post_max_size 200M 
php_value max_input_time 3600 
php_value max_execution_time 3600
```

Comment: **404 : File/Location Not Found**

Comment: Check the location where your buttons redirect! Are they link to the correct files in the correct path?

Comment: Yes, It is the .htaccess problem. Post your .htaccess file here to check the issue.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

</IfModule>

php_value upload_max_filesize 200M  
php_value post_max_size 200M  
php_value max_input_time 3600  
php_value max_execution_time 3600

Comment: please add that to your question and check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676920/codeigniter-showing-only-default-controller)

Comment: "something" is not very informative. Please state what error you are getting. And what do you mean "not taking"?

Comment: How is `$config['base_url']`set in your config? And can you add the location URL that buttons point to, as @HamzaAbdaoui asks above.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

**upload htaccess file in your root floder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: it should be in root directory if you have uploaded it, otherwise create new file and try the above answer or from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676920/codeigniter-showing-only-default-controller)

Comment: This version of `.htaccess` adds some security but no real change to the issue that Raviraj experiences. Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on the server?

Comment: Thank you for your help -shabbirhasan nandoliya